# Is there a way to make a SimpleDB item expire after X amount of time server side using IOS?

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, hmac, amazon-simpledb, hmacsha1

I am making an IOS app with SimpleDB entries that will expire after 30 days. I currently know how to write, read, and delete from SimpleDB, but I have no idea how to make items automatically expire after X amount of time.

I have read about HMAC-SHA signatures with SimpleDB [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonSimpleDB/latest/DeveloperGuide/HMACAuth.html#AboutTimestamp) (It says they can be used to provide an expiration date) and I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476455/is-there-a-library-for-iphone-to-work-with-hmac-sha-1-encoding) saying that one could use CommonCrypto to use HMAC-SHA signatures with AWS (SimpleDB, etc.) on IOS.

My Questions before I proceed: Will that do what I want it to and are there any other ways to make items expire after X amount of time with AWS on IOS?

EDIT: I just found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285595/simpledb-timestamp-on-insert?rq=1). If anybody has anything to add, that would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.